# OneDrive API - Refer to Sharepoint file to upload or download - invalid audience error

Tags: python-2.7, sharepoint, office365, adal, onedrive

I want to programatically interact with files in Office 365 E3 Sharepoint Site.

I am using Azure AD and [ADAL Python library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python) to authenticate access to Sharepoint Site file.

```
import adal
import urllib
import requests
import urllib2

## set variables
username = 'curtis@tenant.onmicrosoft.com'
password = 'OFoarry8Oe$'
authorization_url = 'https://login.windows.net/tenant.onmicrosoft.com' # Authority
redirect_uri = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf'
client_id = 'dcbf844f-d2c3-42d1-8a7d-0f838f57899a' # Client id

## use ADAL to create token response
token_response = adal.acquire_token_with_username_password(
        authorization_url,
        username,
        password
    )
## endpoints discovery
## https://api.office.com/discovery/v2.0/me/allServices

## create refresh token and save it to use later 
refresh_token = token_response['refreshToken']
refresh_token_file = open('refresh_token.txt', 'w')
refresh_token_file.write(refresh_token)
refresh_token_file.close()

## get saved refresh token and use it to get new token response
refresh_token = open('refresh_token.txt', 'r').read()
token_response = adal.acquire_token_with_refresh_token(authorization_url, str(refresh_token))

## get access_token from token response
access_token = token_response.get('accessToken')
headers = {'Authorization':'BEARER ' + str(access_token)}
```

The authentication is successful as I can do

```
print access_token
```

which returns a token string.

I am struggling with the syntax to use to download and upload files from a Sharepoint folder. This is what I have so far:

```
## download file
file_url = 'https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/v1.0/files/root:/myfoldername/myfilename.csv:/content'
r = requests.get(file_url, headers=headers)
print r.text
```

So far I have not been able to successfully refer to the file. I am getting an error:

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Invalid audience Uri 'https:\/\/management.core.windows.net\/'."}
```

This appears to indicate that I am referring to [wrong Site](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lightswitch/2014/03/20/document-libraries-faq-ed-smith/). or perhaps referring to [folder incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635758/onedrive-sharepoint-oauth-invalid-audience-error)

This is a url that I get from the Sharepoint site for the file I want to download (from its properties in Sharepoint):

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/myfoldername/myfilename.csv
```

Does the url of the file from the Sharepoint site  help to define what the `file_url` syntax should be?  If not how else can I determine what the `file_url` should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code, you were authenticate with Azure AD however call the SharePoint REST API. The SharePoint REST is the different authenticate flow. You can refer it from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj687470.aspx).

In your scenario, we can use Microsoft Graph API to download the content from SharePoint site in Office 365. Here is an example that download the content of file on the your default site:

```
GET: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/test.txt:/content

authorization: bearer {token}
```

More detail about Microsoft Graph API, please refer to links below:

https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_downloadcontent

https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_authorization

Comment: Ok that is the issue. Was making assumption that if user was authenticated (my user is account admin) then all permissions would be granted. But not the case.  I might switch to Graph API, it seems better documented.

Answer (score 1):

Fei Xue set me on right path. My code was requesting a resource that ADAL didn't expect.

Turns out `adal.acquire_token_with_username_password` in `__init__.py` has [default values](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/blob/master/adal/__init__.py) (see bottom of code in `class _DefaultValues`) for `client_id` and `resource`.

ADAL's default resource is `https://management.core.windows.net/` which is what it was expecting my `file_url` resource to have. The `invalid audience`was `https://tenant.sharepoint.com`.

So I changed ADAL's default values:

```
`client_id` = my Azure AD app's client_id 
`resource` = `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/`
```

ADAL's `acquire_token_with_username_password` (see below) has `client_id` and `resource` set to `None`. I didn't try but guess these could be edited to remove the `=None` and set in my code instead of `class _DefaultValues`.

```
def acquire_token_with_username_password(
    authority,
    username,
    password,
    client_id=None,
    resource=None,
    validate_authority=True
):
```

And also made minor (but required) change to my `file_url` (url to filename) to :

```
file_url = 'https://pokrant.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drive/root:/analytics/output_analytics.csv:/content'
```

Now when I run code I get the csv file contents printed out in console.